# In GetClientRect rect.bottom rect.right not correct

Tags: winapi

I'm creating a program in which I want to place a button near to bottom-right corner of the Window. I'm using GetClientRect to get top, bottom, right and left of the window. Top and left are working fine but bottom and right are not working. Here's my code:

```
WNDCLASSEX Program;
/*Class declaration*/
hWndMain = CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
                        "Program",
                        "Program",
                        WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2-210,
                        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)/2-135,
                        420,270,
                        HWND_DESKTOP,
                        NULL,hInstance,NULL);
//Window Procedure
WM_CREATE:
{
 RECT MaxSize;
 GetClientRect(hWndMain,&MaxSize);

 /*Menu declaration using CreateMenu, AppendMenu etc*/

 HWND hCalculate = CreateWindowEx(0,WC_BUTTON,
                                           "Calculate",
                                           WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | 0x00000001,
                                           MaxSize.right-156,MaxSize.bottom-51,140,30,
                                           hWnd,(HMENU)IDC_BUTTON1,
                                           GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);
}
```

After compiling the code and running the program I'm not able to see the button. Please help.

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What are the values of `MaxSize` after you call the `GetCLientRect` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assignment to hWndMain looks like it's in your mainline code:

```
hWndMain = CreateWindowEx (WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
```

While this is in the WndProc:

```
//Window Procedure
WM_CREATE:
{
    ...
    GetClientRect(hWndMain,&MaxSize);
```

However, the WM_CREATE message is received and processed *within* the call to CreateWindow, so it hasn't yet returned and so the assignment to hWndMain hasn't yet taken place. So you're likely calling GetClientRect() with an invalid or NULL hWndMain, and it's likely failing and returning an error which you're ignoring. Instead, use the hwnd parameter that's passed to the WndProc.

Comment: Thank you BredanMcK... Your answer worked... I've replaced GetClientRect(hWndMain,&Size) with GetClientRect(hWnd,&Size) and the program is now working fine... Thanks once again...